# Issue in adding onItemSelected attrubute to the spinner with xml

Tags: android

I'm watching a tutorial series and in this tutorial the guy add android:onItemSelected attribute to the spinner xml code for data binding of course he used support library app compat spinner
I'm using androidx app compat spinner but there is no attribute with name android:onItemSelected and no app:onItemSelected

this is my spinner

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:adapter="@{spinnerAdapter}"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:onItemSelected="@{clickHandler::onSelectItem}"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

this is my click handler class

```
  public class MainActivityClickHandlers{

    public void onFABClicked(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAB clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSelectItem(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int pos , long id){
        selectedCategory = (Category) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        String message = "Id is " + selectedCategory.getId()
                + " name , description = " + selectedCategory.getCategoryName() + " , " + selectedCategory.getCategoryDescription();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and this is the error

```
Could not resolve clickHandler::onSelectItem as a listener.

import com.amehrvarz.ebookshop.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
                                      ^
symbol:   class ActivityMainBindingImpl
location: package com.amehrvarz.ebookshop.databinding
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then build and run

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary I did that several times but still have that error . When I writing onItem... there is no guess from android studio. I think there is not an attribute with the name of onItemSelected

Comment: Please provide the link of the tutorial

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhary it's from udemy . at the first chapter of tutorial he used android studio 2.2

Comment: Well, this thing is just apart from your question but I'd suggest you to learn from Udacity, it's a lot better